# How to pass multiple simple parameters from AngularJS to Web API (using $resource)

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass an integer and string parameters from an AngularJS client to an ASP.NET Web API server, without using a POCO class to wrap the parameters in. I've tried the following:

The parameters I want to pass are "id", which is an integer, and "name", a string.

My AngularJS service looks like this:

```
function myResource($resource, myServerUrl) {

    return {
        testFunction: $resource(myServerUrl + "/api/testing/:id/:name/MethodB", null,
        {
            'get': { method: 'GET' }
        })
    };
}
```

The code in the AngularJS controller is the following:

```
var vm = this;

vm.testFunction = function (Id, Name) {
        myResource.testFunction.get({ id: Id, name: Name },
            function(response) {
                // Do something
            },

            // Handles errors
            function(error) {
                // Process error
            });
    }
```

And finally, the Web API controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/testing")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // This is NOT the method I am using for hit example.
    // It's a different one with a similar signature
    // so I am showing it here just in case it has
    // impact on what I am trying to do.
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{name}/{id:int}/MethodA")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetData(string name, int id)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    // This is the method I am using for this example
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{id:int}/{name}/MethodB")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyTestMethod(int id, string name)
    {
        // Do something
    } 

}
```

When I try to run the above code, I get the following error:

> {"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

If I change the code to use POST instead of GET, i.e.:

```
testFunction: $resource(myServerUrl + "/api/testing/:id/:name/MethodB", null,
        {
            'get': { method: 'POST' }
        })
```

and

```
    // This is the method I am using for this example
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}/{name}/MethodB")]
    public IHttpActionResult MyTestMethod(int id, string name)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

I get this:

> {"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}

And if I modify my AngularJS service to not use colon in front of the parameters, i.e. this:

```
testFunction: $resource(myServerUrl + "/api/testing/id/name/MethodB", null,
        {
            'get': { method: 'POST' }
        })
```

I get this error instead:

> {"message":"The request is invalid.","messageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult MyTestMethod(Int32, System.String)' in 'MyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

What is the problem here? How can I pass an integer and a string from AngularJS to a Web API controller, without using a POCO class? I am aware I can wrap both parameters in a value object and pass it that way to the Web API, but that's unnecessary complexity for me at this point. There should be a simple way to do this.

I've done this with two or three integer parameters without a problem, but for some reason an integer and a string is not working. Any advice on this would be appreciated. It's one of those things that should be simple to do, but apparently it's not.

Comment: Test your API isolated with Postman, to ensure Backend works fine

Comment: This is an API that has been in production for years. I just added this new method, MyTestMethod, for my particular scenario. I don't think the API is the problem. It has to be something with the way I am calling it, or possibly the way I am defining the route above method MyTestMethod.

Comment: Also, what about the more general question, how would you pass an integer and a string from AngularJS to a Web API?

Comment: For Post I do like this public IHttpActionResult MyTestMethod([FromBody]int id)

Comment: @CryingFreeman I tried that, but it didn't work for me. Could you give a code sample (consisting of Angular JS controller, AngularJS resource, and a Web API controller)?

Comment: Does it have to be an integer that you pass? Can't the ID be a string then later on the server-side code you convert it back to int? I find that passing around integers when they aren't going to be used for math leads to many hours of confusing debugging..

Comment: @I.R.R. Yes, the ID can be a string. I could just cast it to an Int on the backend.

Comment: If you changed `"/api/testing/:id/:name/MethodB"` to `"/api/testing/" + id "/" + name + "/MethodB"` would that make a difference? I had a similar issue passing a variable to web api because of that and also I had to put another variable in square brackets before it would register.

Comment: @I.R.R. I don't think you can do that with a service type component utilizing $resource (like the one I have above), because you don't have access to the parameter values in it. You can do that with $http, but not $resource, as far as I know, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @lukegf let me post my code where a service did exactly that. Hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's an example where I passed an object from controller to service, and the service uses $resource

```
var navApp = angular.module('navApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate'    
]);


navApp.controller('menuController', [
    '$scope',
    'navSectionList',
    'navGetCategories',

    function ($scope, navSectionList, navGetCategories) {
        $scope.navSectionList = navSectionList.query();
        $scope.getSectionID = function (event) {
            $scope.navGetCategories = navGetCategories
                .getResource([event])
                .query();
        };
    }
]);

navApp.factory('navSectionList', [
    '$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/navigation/section/list', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }
]);

navApp.factory('navGetCategories', [
    '$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        var service = {
            getResource: function (sectionID) {
                return $resource('/api/navigation/category/' + sectionID, {}, {
                    query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
                });
            }
        };
    return service; 
    }
]);
```

`getSectionID` kept passing `undefined` to `navGetCategories.getResource()` until I put `event` into a box `[event]`.

I still don't really know why it wouldn't work without the square brackets, maybe someone else can explain why.

Comment: Interesting, so you can actually pass values of parameters in a $resource service. That is kind of what I was looking for, although I did solve my problem yesterday in a different way. What I found out was that my Web API method ('MyTestMethod' above) wasn't being found because of the other method in the same class with a similar signature. Once I moved it into its own, new Web API controller and changed the route to something unique, things started working.

Answer (score 1):

well, I do it this way

Server

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Api/Account/GetPasswordReset")]
        public dynamic GetPasswordReset(string UserName, string OldPassword, string NewPassword)
        {}
```

Client

```
$http({
            method: "GET",           
            url: CTHelper.ApiUrl() + '/Api/Account/GetPasswordReset?UserName=' + CTHelper.UserName()
                + '&OldPassword=' + $scope.CurrentPassword + '&NewPassword=' + $scope.NewPassword,
        }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

        }, function myError(response) {
             });
```

Comment: Your example uses the $http directive. I want to use $resource.